# Connect to TFS with VS Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, tfs, tfvc

i am trying to connect with VS Code to TFS.
I managed to install addon "Argutec Azure Repos" created local workspace changed path for TF.exe in VS Code and even get pop up that is asking me for name and passoword.

However after i enter credentials nothing happens, and icon in the left bottom corner shows only "Unathorized...".

I am not sure if this should even work or is maintained VS Code addon. If you know whats wrong please let me know or if you know any better way how to connect VSCode with TFS(TFVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the workspace is already created and is of type `Local` for the extension to work. If needed run:

```
tf workspace /location:local /noprompt
```

This will switch over the repository to a local workspace.

Then using PAT or "new auth workflow" succeeds on my end.

### Note:

The official Azure Repos extension has been discontinued and deprecated. It's no longer officially supported.

> ### Sunsetting the Azure Repos VS Code extension
>
> We're sunsetting this Azure Repos VS Code extension. On 2020-11-06 (Nov 6, 2020), we'll remove it from the VS Code Marketplace and archive the repository. If you still have it installed, you may continue to use it, but it will not receive any further investment or updates.
>
> ### Why are we doing this?
>
> Since we launched the extension four and a half years ago, Visual Studio Code has seen incredible adoption. Azure DevOps and Azure Repos have similarly continued to see amazing growth. However, use of TFVC, the centralized source control system, with VS Code has declined. The majority of VS Code users prefer Git, and therefore use of the extension has declined dramatically in the last 1-2 years. VS Code has great native Git support. Therefore we have taken the decision to discontinue support of this extension. Developers still using TFVC with VS Code will need to use an external version control client such as the tf command line.
>
> ### What happened?
>
> We shipped a final update which contains this notice but contains no other functional changes, bug fixes, etc.
>
> On 2020-11-06 we unpublished the extension from the Visual Studio Code Marketplace. Those who already have it installed can continue to use it, but without support from Microsoft. The extension won't receive any updates, bug fixes, or security fixes, so you use it at your own risk.
>
> We archived the GitHub repository putting it into a read-only state. This will not delete the code or historical issues (though all open issues and PRs were closed). The repository is still readable and forkable.

<sup>[notice](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/DEPRECATED.md#sunsetting-the-azure-repos-vs-code-extension)</sup>

[You can get the last released version from the Releases tab on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/releases).

The official supported path is to install Visual Studio Team Explorer alongside VSCode and use them side-by-side.

This fork seems to have made no substantial changes to the project

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Its local workspace otherwise i get error. I checked it in VS. But it still wont work somehow. Anyway thanks again for your help.

Comment: I looked into it as well, getting all kinds of errors. I'm guessing that something changed on the vscode side which broke the extension.

Comment: Yeah probably .